# Need help identifying 2 old coins? Struck coins, one with two standing human figures facing each other

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome, identification, currency, numismatics

Can anyone tell me what these 2 coins are ?
How can I safely clean them?[image]

Comment: Can you tell us anything else about them, like where they were found? Also, it would help if you gave the dimensions.

Comment: Another way to clean coins is with electrolysis; I've used it to remove decades of rust from old wrought iron.  Follow the safety precautions, and do it outside, or in a very well ventilated space.

Comment: How wise or desirable is it to clean old, possibly classical coins?   How much cleaning, if any, is too little, how much cleaning, if any, is just enough, and how much cleaning would be too much, for the sake of the hypothetical resale value of the coins.  I personally think that the coins would look much better if cleaned a lot, but I don't know how that would affect their hypothetical resale values.

Comment: Don't clean old coins as it ruins resale value

Answer (score 15):

The first coin doesn't have much detail to go by.
But the second coin looks like it might have [two soldiers standing with banners](https://www.coinarchives.com/a/results.php?results=100&search=gloria+exercitvs). Some Roman coins have that. Here's an example of a coin with Constantine I, c 334-335:

[image: Constantine I]

There are a couple of pages with [coin cleaning tips](http://www.forumancientcoins.com/Articles/Uncleaned_Ancient_Coins.html) on the web. In short: toothpicks, toothbrushes, soap, and (distilled) water; gently, with a lot of care and patience.